# Colorbox under graphix hasn't the same width

Tags: multicol

In my document I want the `fcolorbox` the same width as the graphics, but I can't get it right. The left side is aligned (wich is good) but the right side is not (which is bad ...)

What is going wrong here?

```
\documentclass[11pt,landscape,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[english,dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{../graph/}{../tek/}}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}

\parbox[t]{1.0\linewidth}{
    \includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{joec.jpg}\hfill
    \vspace{-5.0pt}
    \fcolorbox{gray}{gray}{\parbox{1.0\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{
                        \color{white}
                        \raggedleft{\small{text text text} }
                    }
                }
}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spurious blank spaces (I removed them in my code by deleting some and some others using `%`); you were missing `\dimexpr` in the calculation of the `\parbox` width:

```
\documentclass[11pt,landscape,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[english,dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{../graph/}{../tek/}}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\noindent\parbox[t]{1.0\linewidth}{%
\includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{joec.jpg}\hfill\par\nointerlineskip
\fcolorbox{gray}{gray}{%
  \parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}{\color{white}%
  \raggedleft{\small text text text}
  }%
}%
}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `demo` option for `graphicx` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document.

Comment: Thanx, this solved my problem, but raised another question which was solved by this answer: [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines]