# Using multicol for framed figure

Tags: pdftex, multicol

I have some figures in my `article`. I want the figures to be framed. I managed to do this with the `figure` and `floatrow` packages. But I have a problem of changing the size of the frame, such that I have to reduce the figure size for it to fit in the frame.
Then I cam across [Colorbox under graphix hasn't the same width](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109394/colorbox-under-graphix-hasnt-the-same-width), from which I adapted the following mwe:

```
\documentclass[b5paper,11pt,fleqn,leqno,parskip=full]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english,dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\graphicspath{ {../Images} }

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\noindent\parbox[t]{1.2\linewidth}{%
\fcolorbox{gray}{gray}{\includegraphics[width=2.5\linewidth]{../Images/precip_corr.jpg}
  \parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}{\color{white}%
  \raggedright{Areas of Significant El Nino-Related Precip Anomalies.\\ \small source: Ropelewski and Halpert.}
  }%
}%
}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

This example works for me, except I want the caption below the figure. Moreover I do not understand the various arguments, changing by trial and error has not been useful, except:

1.2 in  `\noindent\parbox[t]{1.2` and `\includegraphics[width=2.5.`

I hope someone can help me:

a) get the caption below, if possible
b) explain

`{3}` in `\begin{multicols}{3}`

`[t]` in `\noindent\parbox[t]`

`-2` in `\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2`

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Why are you using the `multicols` environment? I mean, why do you need it?

Comment: As I said with the figure/subcaption environment I cannot change the size of the frame. I will post another question, maybe I can be helped with the figure/subcaption environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can safely switch to using `mdframed` for the background, the size can be easily changed, so if that's why you had the `multicols` package, you can remove it.

Below is an example with a `\newcommand`. The color of the background is optional (default white).

Regarding your questions:

1. The number `3` in multicols denotes the number of **col**umns the text splits into.
2. The option `[t]` in `parbox` is the text alignment, that goes:

   - `[t]` — text is placed at the top of the box.
   - `[c]` — text is centered vertically.
   - `[b]` — text is placed at the bottom.
   - `[s]` — stretch vertically. Note that the text must contain vertically stretchable space for this to work.
3. `\linewidth-2` basically is removing `2` from the value of `\linewidth`.

---

**Note:** the margins have been altered to show the pages closer for this screenshot. Click the image to view it better.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[b5paper,11pt,fleqn,leqno]{article} % parskip=full was unused
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english,dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{cleveref} % clever referencing that adds "fig.", etc, automatically
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed} % required for drawing the background + line color
\usepackage{float} % needed to use [H]

\newcommand\bfig[4][white]{
  \begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{mdframed}[linecolor=#1,backgroundcolor=#1]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\dimexpr\textheight-4\baselineskip-\abovecaptionskip-\belowcaptionskip\relax,keepaspectratio]{#2}
    \caption[caption]{#3}\label{#4}
    \vspace{10pt}
    \end{mdframed}
  \end{figure}
}

\begin{document}

\bfig{example-image-a}{Areas of Significant El Nino-Related Precip Anomalies.\\\hspace{\textwidth}\small Source: Ropelewski and Halpert.}{imagea}

As showed in \cref{imagea}, A is the best letter.

\bfig[gray]{example-image-b}{Areas of Significant El Nino-Related Precip Anomalies.\\\hspace{\textwidth}\tiny Source: Ropelewski and Halpert.}{imageb}

While \cref{imageb}, well, not really...
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks very much @Alenanno, I will go with the mdframed it does what I want, and thanks for explaining the multicol options.

Comment: @ZiloreMumba No problem! You can try pasting a very long Lorem Ipsum inside a `multicols` environment and try changing the number. :)

Comment: @ZiloreMumba Note that I used `\small` in the first example and `\tiny` in the second one. I think it's still readable. You could also use `\scriptsize`.

Comment: or others who may read this, I have worked with the code you gave me and it is fine for my purpose. I have been trying to figure out, how do I adjust the figure size? I will need this for some figures.

Comment: @ZiloreMumba Have you tried changing the options for `\includegraphics`? Check between the square brackets. :)

Comment: the only change I tried is to put "[scale=num]" in place of "width=\textwidth". When I put scale<1 (say 0.5) the framed reduces but not the figure. scale >1 makes the figure too large to invisible on the right. Is there anything else I can change ,e.g. in "height=\dimexpr\textheight-4\baselineskip-\abovecaptionskip-\belowcaptionskip\relax"?

Comment: Looks like I can no longer get @Alenanno to assist me. can anyone suggest to me how I can make the graphic in the above code scale down to less than 100%? Currently I can only get it to textwidth/linewidth or larger. Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: @ZiloreMumba I think it's safe for you to ask a follow-up question, since it looks to me like a separate issue, you can also link to this one in the new one to provide some context.